# How does the android load the resources(string)?

Tags: android, resources, loading

How does the android load the **res(string)?**

We all know that: the string resources are in the values folder.

There're some kinds folders.

**Such as:**

```
 values
 values-es
 values-mcc460
```

When the user change the language to `Spanish`, then the system would load the resource from the folder `values-es.`
And when the user insert a sim card(mcc=460), then the system would load the resource from the folder values-mcc460.

I wanna know how the system exactly load the resource? How does the android implement the resource loading mechanism in the framework?
I'm not familiar with c/c++.

Help!

Comment: I don't mean this. I wanna know how the system know that which folder should be used.

Comment: for that you will have to look at the source code implementation of resources class

Comment: You're right. I find the method AssetManager.getResourceText returns the string. But it use a native method loadResourceValue. But I'm not familiar with c/c++, so I need help.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/content/res/Resources.java. check this. try understanding the methods. I guess it uses a string table or string block.